# Trying to find different methods of accessing array elements?

Tags: c

I am new to C but determined to learn good C. I need your help. While practising arrays, I just thought to find out that the way I am accessing array element is right or maybe there might be a better way to do it. Please check the following code and suggest a good way of using array with pointers. 
I would really appreciate if somebody can guide me to a tutorial for advance practice of array with pointers.

```
int main()
{
   unsigned int i, j;
   unsigned int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

   unsigned int * ptr_arr = (unsigned int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
   ptr_arr = arr1;

   for(i=0;i<=8;i++)
   {
         printf("Value at location %d\t is:  %d\n",i,*(ptr_arr+i));
         printf("\n");         
         printf("Value of i %d and value at %d\n",i, ptr_arr[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eh, since you're new you probably don't know this one: `i[ptr_arr]`.

Comment: Take a look at Steve Summit's ["Introduction to C programming"](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html) (somewhat dated, but still excellent). Some of the best resources on C are collected [here](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c). Do _not_ get lured into "writing this convoluted, smart code, I'll get better performance". It won't, write clean, simple code. Somebody said "To debug code requires twice as much intelligence as to write it. If we write our code as smartly as we can, who will be able to debug it?".

Answer (score 4):

You program is leaking memory

> unsigned int * ptr_arr = (unsigned int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));

There is no need to allocate memory for ptr_arr.

assignment of address of arr1 is enough

> ptr_arr = arr1;

Another way to use it is increment the pointer every time and use it

```
    ptr_array2 = arr1
    for (int i = 0; i < 8 ; i++)
    {
       printf ("%d", *ptr_array2);
       ptr_array2++;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Both ways of accessing an element in the array are *valid*. But for readability sake, use `array[subscript]` instead of `*(arrayStart+index)`.

Example:

```
int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
```

In an array, the elements are contiguously placed, beginning at `array(say address 0x00000000)`. Assuming a 32 bit integer size, `2` is placed at address of `array + 4`, which is at address `0x00000004`, similarly the next element `3` is at address `array + 8`, which is address `0x00000008` and so on.

When I write `array[2]` I mean I want the second element **after** the element at `array`(or `array[0]`) which is actually the 3rd element in the array. Hence, array indexes start at `0`.

It literally means, `array[0]` = `*(array + 0)`, `array[1]` = `*(array + 1)`, `array[2]`=`*(array+2)`

Answer (score 0):

You need not allocate memory for ptr_arr as you are anyway assigning the address of arr to ptr_arr. Your above code will lead to a memory leak.

You can refer to one of numerous tutorials available in the internet. Just for reference I am posting a few links:

http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp221/html/pdf/03-arrays-pointers.pdf
http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/fussell/courses/cs310h/lectures/Lecture_17-310h.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You missed one method:

```
     printf("Value of i %d and value at %d\n",i, i[ptr_arr]);
```

Comment: can you add further explanation to this answer?

Comment: internally c handles any array[index] into *(array+index) so writing array[index] or index[array] will be same ie *(array+index). You can even use negative numbers as subscripts too like array[-1]. But make sure of the array bounds