# Not able to access array elements?

Tags: c

i have this array where i am trying to access its elements by incrementing ptr, as suggested here <strike>[Trying to find different methods of accessing array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104339/trying-to-find-different-methods-of-accessing-array-elements)</strike>...i must be doing something stupid...please help me!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
   int i;

   char *p1 = "Cnversions";  
   char *p2 = "Divided";  
   char *p3 = "Plain";  
   char *p4 = "Solid";  

   char *arr[3];

   arr[0] = p1;
   arr[1] = p2;
   arr[2] = p3;
   arr[3] = p4;



   for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
   {

      printf("string at arr[%d] is: %s\n",i,*arr);

     arr++;
    }

   return 0;

  }
```

Comment: Do not increment `arr`. Also `arr` should be of size 4.

Comment: For safety reasons and good programming practice, p1 to p4, as well as arr, should be declared as `const`.

Answer (score 5):

An array like `arr` is located at a *specific* spot in memory, so it makes no sense to increment `arr` (what does it mean to increment an array?)

Instead, you will need to create a pointer to the start of the array and increment the pointer:

```
char **ptr = arr;
for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
    printf("arr[%d] = %s\n", i, *ptr);
    ptr++;
}
```

(Note also that you need to make `arr` four elements big, i.e. `char *arr[4]`, to accommodate the four string pointers you put in it.)

Answer (score -1):

Remember that although we tend to think of double pointers as arrays, all the compiler sees them as are pointers. When you increment a pointer, it adds a value to the address of the pointer equal to the size of the data type it's pointing at. For example:

```
int *p;
p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

`p` is pointing to an `int`, so the size of `p`'s pointed data is (typically) 4 bytes. This means when you increment `p`, it will be pointing at a location 4 bytes greater than where it was before.

The type of `arr` is a `char**`, meaning that it's a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. Pointers on most machines these days are 8 bytes. So when you incrementing `arr`, you are effectively telling the computer to set `arr` to point to an address 8 bytes higher than what it was at before. In the case of `arr`, this is an illegal address, so you'll get some kind of crash.